# Reading many API feeds and processing data in "one call" PHP and avoiding a timeout

Tags: php, api, timeout

Well a question I wanted to ask for a while but it is getting more and more the right time to ask it.

---

I am building a system in PHP that processes bookings for holiday facilities.

Every facility (hotel, motel, hostel, bead & breakfast etc etc) has it's own login and is able to manage its own bookings.

Now it is being ran on a system with a single database that separates the user data at the hand of the hostname & user & login.

Also the system is equipped with the option to import bookings provided by partner / resellers.
I have created a specific page for doing this.

> Let's say :
>   ***cron.examplesystem.com***

This URL is called by the Cron task every 5 minutes to check if there are any new bookings or any pending changes / cancellations or confirmations.

**Now the issue**

---

This is going just fine until now.

However we had one instance for every client. And generally every call had to process something between 3 to 95 bookings.

But as I now updated my system from one instance for every client I work with one instance for all clients.

> So in the past : 
>   ***myclient.myholidaybookings.example.com***
>
> I am now going to :
>   ***myholidaybookings.example.com***

With one server to handle all clients instead of multiple servers for each client his own.

This will put a lot of stress on the server. And this in general is none of my worries since I have worked hard to make it manageable and scalable.

But I have no clue how to approach this.

Because let's say we have about 100 clients with each 3 - 95 bookings (average 49) we'll have 490 bookings or updates to process a time.
For sure we'll be having a timeout soon or later.

And this is what I want to prevent.
Now all kind of creative solutions are to be found. But what's best practice. I want to create a solution that is solid and doesn't have to be reworked half way going live.

**Summary :**

---

problem : I have a system that processes many API feeds in one call and I am sure we'll have a timeout when processing if the system gets populated with users
desired solution : a best practice approach in PHP how to handle and process many API feeds without worrying about a timeout when the user database is growing.

Comment: Is your issue storing data as it arrives in a timely manner?

Comment: The problem is mainly that the amount of data to be processed is in a large volume. But I cannot accept to set a delay from one hour. I have been thinking of setting some kind of a queue. But this isn't an option since we might have 100 different users that each have 10 different partners with each their own API connection and each their own required call of updating and adding.

Comment: Perhaps you should explore some sort of multitenancy setup, split the data into multiple databases with the same structure, then use a "system" database to manage the flow of data, this way you can reduce the amount of data indexing per client.